# How to add a custom domain to Azure static web app by api

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-api-management, azure-static-web-app, azure-custom-domain

I need to add custom domain to Azure static web app by an automate process. Eg: I have a web app and it has admin side and user side. A new user registered to the admin app they can add a new subdomain to the user app.

So I want to add that created subdomain details to the azure static web -> custom domain when newly registered user of the admin app finish the registration.

Can some one navigates through the process, how to archive this.

Thank you.

Comment: Azure has a bunch of APIs. Have you researched?

Comment: I don't think Azure let you to create multiple subdomains with management api, but if you are looking for multitenant solution look this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/considerations/domain-names

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do can be done from the command line.
Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/hostname?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to use *wildcard custom domain* which would allow users to access the site using subdomain.

For more information you can refer [Azure Websites and wildcard domains](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-and-wildcard-domains/)

**REFERENCES:**
[Custom domains with Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain)